# Request for hint: introductory complex analysis problem

Tags: complex-analysis

*This is not a ‘do-my-homework’ question.*

The problem is

> For what value of $a$, is $$F(z)=\int^z_{z_0}e^z\left(\frac1z+\frac{a}{z^3}\right)dz$$ single-valued?

The answer is $a=-2$.

I am **not asking** for a full solution; I just hope someone can give me a hint, as I have no idea how this problem can be solved.

p.s. I am aware of a theorem stating that $$f(z)=\int_C\frac{\phi(x)}{x-z}dx$$ is an analytic function for continuous $\phi$ and $z$ outside $C$. However, I don’t see how this theorem can be applied. Moreover, analyticity is too strong in comparison to single-valued-ness.

Comment: The integral is single-valued if it does not depend on the chosen path from $z_0$ to $z$. That is, if the integral of $e^{z}\bigl(\frac{1}{z} + \frac{a}{z^3}\bigr)$ over every closed path in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ is $0$. It suffices to look at one suitable closed path.

Comment: Wow!,The integral is single-valued if it does not depend on the chosen path from $z_{0}$ to $z$. can you give a reference to this statement.@DanielFischer, this reminds of the concept of conservative force

Comment: @DanielFischer But I don’t see how this would lead to $a=-2$...

Comment: How far have you come on your journey into complex analysis? Do you know Cauchy's integral formula and integral theorem already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** \begin{align}f\text{ is single-valued}&\iff\text{for every loop }\gamma,\ \displaystyle\int_\gamma e^z\left(\frac 1z+\frac a{z^3}\right)\,\mathrm dz=0\\&\iff\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(e^z\left(\frac 1z+\frac a{z^3}\right)\right)=0.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks you! Very helpful!

Comment: Not a useful comment but still one can wonder $f$ here, could have been written for a general one and then particular $f$!